# Facing problems using MacBook Pro M1 chip

Tags: github, networking, terminal, apple-m1

i've been trying to install software like Homebrew, flutter etc through the terminal and i've been getting the same error codes:

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error: Fetching /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
fatal: invalid upstream 'origin/master'
Failed during: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

I'm using the new Macbook Pro and having been trying to find a fix to this issue since i got this device. I've contacted the developers of Homebrew, and they said it was a security issue, i asked apple and they couldn't help. I've tried removing the failed install with:

> rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core)

However, this didn't fix my problem. I also tried 3 different networks, one of them being the 4G on my phone. I can't seem to get around this problem. When i try install dependancies with flutter i get the same errors so it's not one install that's raising the problem.

Full command line for the Homebrew install:

```
HEAD is now at 8853fb6c1 Merge pull request #11145 from Bo98/json-tab-changed_files-fix
error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error: Fetching /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
fatal: invalid upstream 'origin/master'
Failed during: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

Has any one faced this problem before, or know of a fix? any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: can you try this - https://medium.com/swlh/issues-installing-homebrew-on-new-macbook-m1-silicon-heres-how-to-fix-it-8b63921c7290

Comment: When i first came across this error I found this article, but sadly it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of solutions to this problem. It boiled down to my ISP provider (Virgin UK) who was bottlenecking the install, probably because of a security issue or bug.

A solution that worked for me was removing the initial failed installation and using a VPN to changing my connection and install it that way.

A second solution would be turning off Child Safe with your ISP.

These are the solutions I came across, the first one worked for me, and I have been told that the second one works too!